# How to get the string value of a NSScrollView in Swift (OSX)?

Tags: macos, swift

I would like to get the string value of a NSScrollView object, but I can’t find any function, is there a way to get the string value?

Comment: What do you expect the "string value" to be?  A scroll view doesn't even have any text on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every subclass of `NSObject` has a `description` method that returns an `NSString`. Depending on what your use case is, that should work.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I just ran into the same problem and I believe I know what the OP did to get confused:

I come from an iOS background and I'm not used to the extra UI control layers used in IB for Mac OS development.  When you drag a text view from the palette to the canvas, it gives it to you embedded in a scrollview...and when I hooked up the outlets, I wasn't paying attention, and connected the scroll view rather than the text view.

I had to go back to my storyboard, drill down into the scroll view that housed my text view, and hook up the outlet with the actual text view.  Once I did that, yes, there is a .string property that is exactly what most people will want.

Answer (score 0):

A NSScrollView doesn't have a `stringValue` method. It is a container of document view.

Answer (score 0):

if we have some object like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!
```

then we can do

```
if let text = scrollView.documentView as? NSTextView {
            print(text.string) // to get text value
            text.string = "setting new text"
}
```